# Converting R Markdown Files to Email

Tags: html, r, email, svg, r-markdown

I've been working in R markdown to create graphs based on a provided dataset. My employer  wants me to convert it to an email format, so that they can send out large batches of automated emails to their clients with my graphs in them. The end product would look like this:

To: client@gmail.com

From: company@gmail.com

Hi (Client Name),

This is your annual report. You made (variable) amount of money.

(Graph)

Thank you for being a customer.

Best,

Company

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The `emayili` package may be suitable to your need https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emayili/readme/README.html

Answer (score 1):

The `blastula` package provides exactly what you are trying to do. You can generate emails using the example template below:

````
---
title: "ClientReport"
author: "ADFH"
date: "8/21/2021"
output: blastula::blastula_email

runtime: shiny

params: 
  clientName: "Name not Set"
  money: "unknown"
  
---

To: client@gmail.com

From: company@gmail.com

Hi `r params$clientName`

This is your annual report. You made (variable) amount of money.

```{r, echo=F, include=T}
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(Money=c(0, 100), Client = c("Other People", "You"))

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=Client, y=Money), stat = 'identity') + ggplot2::theme_minimal() 
```

Thank you for being a customer.

Best,

Company
````

The above template has to be rendered using `blastula::render_email`, then distributed:

```
f = blastula::render_email('test.Rmd'
                       , output_options = list(params = params)
                       , envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) %>% 
blastula::smtp_send(
  from = "xxx@gmail.com",
  to = "recipient@wherever.com",
  subject = "Your email subject",
  credentials = creds_key("gmail")
)
```

The above example shows show to send emails using gmail - other smtp providers work similarly. The `creds_key` uses the `keyring` package. For gmail, the credentials key can be generated using

```
blastula::create_smtp_creds_key(
  id = "gmail2",
  user = "xxxx@gmail.com",
  host = "smtp.gmail.com",
  port = 465,
  use_ssl = TRUE
)
```

Your company probably has a different email solution, which should likely be configured differently.